# AWS restrict IAM user to update storage class for s3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need to write an IAM policy to restrict my IAM user, that the user can not able to update the s3 objects storage class or a default class is apply to all object and user will not be able to update its class by AWS console.

Screenshots for reference.
[image]

[image]

I have tried with below policy but its not working -

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "restrictStorageClass",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "s3:x-amz-storage-class": [
                    "STANDARD"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Did you try something and is not working? could you please explain it?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the policy from which I have tried to restrict the user.

Comment: The `PutObjectVersionTagging` command is used to add tags to an object. It doesn't have anything to do with Storage Classes. Are you only concerned with _changing_ storage class, or do you also need to restrict the storage class when an object is initially Uploaded? Is there a particular storage class you want to _always_ use for the bucket, or are you only trying to limit certain people from changing the storage class?

Comment: I need to restrict the user from changing the storage class, means whatever the default storage class will not be changed by the AWS console by an IAM user.